# H2 query failing with 'No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode'

Tags: hibernate, h2

I have a custom query that works with postgres but is failing with H2.

```
select distinct(to_char(date_requested,'YYYY')) 
from Product 
where date_requested is not null
```

The exception I get is:

```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
     \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
        +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'to_char' {originalText=to_char}
        \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
           +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'date_requested' {originalText=date_requested}
           \-[QUOTED_STRING] LiteralNode: ''YYYY''
```

Another query I have, with similar use of to_char, works just fine:

```
select count(*), requester 
from Product 
where to_char(date_requested,'YYYY') = '2016' 
group by requester 
ORDER BY Count(*) desc
```

I do have the latest version of H2, 1.4.192, so I know that to_char usage is okay.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the first query not working with H2?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is ***NOT***  a function. Putting an expression between parentheses won't change anything for distinct. `distinct  (a)` is the same as `distinct a`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. It's a colleague's query that I'm writing unit tests for. Anyway, yes, unrelated. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Does the query work when run without the obfuscation layer (aka ORM)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to check this. My DBMS is using an older version of the H2 driver that doesn't support to_char. Changing it to use the latest H2 driver jar (taken from [link](http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html), I get an error **java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/h2/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0** when I try to connect to the H2 database.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

By using latest version of H2, these TO_DATE, TRUNC, TO_CHAR functions are presents in H2.

The problem here is that you are using hibernate as ORM backend, and the regular H2Dialect doesn't understand these functions. You can subclass this dialect to map new functions. For example, here is the one I use for TRUNC function.

```
package my.awesome.project;

import org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class CustomH2Dialect extends H2Dialect {

    public CustomH2Dialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("trunc", new StandardSQLFunction("trunc", StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP));
    }
}
```

And you replace hibernate settings 'connection.driver_class' by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

  <persistence-unit name="thePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:./db/repository"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="my.awesome.project.CustomH2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue went away when I removed the to_char function from all my queries. A colleague tells me that H2 does not support the use of functions. I could not find any documentation to support the same, but thought I would leave this here as an option in case somebody else faces this problem.